# Quick Sort Algorithm with Constant Partition

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity, quicksort

I ran into a question about Quick Sort Algorithm. this is take from 2010-midterm exam on data structure from Chinese University, CS 234.

Suppose in Quick Sort, Partition procedure take C times, (consume constant time). if we use random data as input, what is the order (time complexity) of Randomized-Quick Sort?

Anyone could describe the time complexity in this manner?

EDIT:

I calculate these relations. my work is correct? anyone could clarify me?

```
Best Case: T(n)=2T(n/2)+C= Theta (n)

Worst Case: T(n)=2T(n-1)+C= Theta (n)
```

Comment: Answer could be found on wikipedia

Comment: Dear @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, I know Theta (n), but I confused how get it !

Comment: Good lecture notes here: [Analysis of Algorithms I: Randomized Quicksort](http://alg12.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/QUICKSORT.pdf). I'm not sure what you mean by a "constant partition", though. Each iteration of the of the partition/sort uses a different value.

Comment: Dear @jww, suppose we have an algorithm that partition take C times always. now, what is the T(N)?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26207040/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29357/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the expected running time: expected value of `T(n)`. So let `T(n)` be the random variable for running time. There are `n` possible outcomes each of which corresponds to a partition:

```
T(0) + T(n-1) + c
T(1) + T(n-2) + c
...
T(n-1) + T(0) + c
```

One of these is going to be picked, let `X(i) = 1 if T(i) + T(n - i - 1) + c` is picked and `0` otherwise. The recurrence for `T(n)` can then be written as:

```
T(n) = X(0)(T(0) + T(n-1) + c) + ... + X(n-1)(T(n-1) + T(0) + c)
```

Now to calculate the expectation, we write:

```
E( T(n) ) = E( X(0)(T(0) + T(n-1) + c) + ... + X(n-1)(T(n-1) + T(0) + c) )
          = (1/n)E(2T(0) + 2T(1) + ... + 2T(n-1) + cn)
          = (2/n)(E((T(0)) + ... + E(T(n-1))) + c.
```

Third line was obtained by linearity of expectation. At this point we are going to guess the answer for `E( T(i) )` and use induction to prove it. This technique is called substitution.

- Guess: `E( T(i) ) <= Ai`, for `A > 0` and `1 <= i < n`.
- Base: for i = 1, array is already sorted so expected running time is constant.
- Induction: `E( T(n) ) <= (2A/n)(n(n-1)/2) = A(n-1) <= An`.

So claim holds for n. The expected running time is `O(n)`.